# Adding dynamic data in table in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, mysql, css, asp.net

I saw many posts in stackoverflow but they didn't help me much. about adding data and designing the table. by adding data I mean simple. like, name: John. work: designer. etc..

the code for the table for now is this:

```
<asp:Table ID="table1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>Name</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>Task</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>Hours</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

and the css design behind the table is this:

```
#table1 {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    top: 200px;
    left: 315px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

for now, I was adding data like this:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow();
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
      
cell1.Text = "wow";
row.Cells.Add(cell1);
table1.Rows.Add(row);
```

but it adds just a single text..

also.. when I change the data or make any change to the table. it disappears.. I dont understand why..
I set z-index to 10 for max. while the biggest index for the panel is like 3...

I am not being able to design the table too..
this is how it looks now:
[image: img1]

and this is how I am trying to make it look like:
[image: img2]
(forget the image at first. just text for now)

any help? I cant figure this out.. even tho I've been working with this for past 2 hours.. (I'm new to asp.net and cant learn fast)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here but you only run this line once: `row.Cells.Add(cell1);` ... so there should be only one text added. What if you run it twice?

Comment: @LGSon nothing changes.. also, the table disappears after I refresh the page. just need to edit anything in the css file for it to show up again